# Assign variable once when first used in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How do I only invoke a make `shell` function once in a variable expansion, and only when the variable is first used? I don't want to use `:=` to expand at declaration time (ie: simple expansion) because the expansion is expensive and only some of my targets need the variable.

I tried using conditional variable assignment but it invokes the shell every time, for example, the following invokes `shell ls` twice:

```
.PHONY: test

FILES ?= $(warning Invoking the shell)$(shell ls)

test:
    echo $(FILES) one
    echo $(FILES) two
```

Comment: A longer writeup is here: http://make.mad-scientist.net/deferred-simple-variable-expansion/

Answer (score -1):

Move the assignment inside the recipe

```
test:
    FILES=$$(ls) ;\
    echo $$FILES one ;\
    echo $$FILES two
```